# How to calculate tab length till the end of the String?

Tags: java

I am spliting the String by tab like

```
String s = "1"+"\t"+2+"\t"+3+"\t"+"4";
System.out.println("length : "+ s.split("\\t").length);
```

In this case i get the length 4. But if i remove the last element 4 & give only blank, like

```
String s = "1"+"\t"+2+"\t"+3+"\t"+"";
System.out.println("Length : "+ s.split("\\t").length);
```

In this case i got the output 3. it means this is not calculating last tab.
In below case also, i need the length 4. This scenario i am using in my project & getting undesired result.
So please suggest me, How to calculate the entire length of tab delimited string, whether the last element is also blank.
Such as, if the case is,

```
String s = "1"+"\t"+2+"\t"+3+"\t"+"";
System.out.println("Length : "+ s.split("\\t").length);
```

then the answer should be 4 & if the case is,

```
String s = "1"+"\t"+2+"\t"+3+"\t"+"" + "\t"+ "";
System.out.println("Length : "+ s.split("\\t").length);
```

then the answer should be 5.

Please provide me the appropriate answer.

Comment: Instead of splitting the string and counting the length of the split array, why not just iterate over the string, and count the tabs? You can use the `String.matches()` method for every character and find the answer that way.

Comment: If you expect 5, do `s.split("\t", 5)`. Then it will give 5 on 4 tabs, and 3 on two tabs. Also only one backslash is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent `split` from removing trailing empty spaces you need to use `split(String regex, int limit)` with negative `limit` value like

```
split("\t", -1)
```

Comment: Thanks Pshemo, This is working fine now.